# Adaptive stopping rule for spatially autocorrelated Poisson data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, poisson-distribution, spatial, proportion

I have a problem where I am given an initial prior or proportion for the number of occurrences per some unit with known standard deviation (an example is 3 per mile).

I wish to test if this proportion is valid given a live exhaustive sampling of the area.  So I would plan to use all the sampled information.

I understand that something like a z test for proportions works when you are working with a given sample size (as this is used in calculating a test deviation).  One way I have though of solving this is to simply break down the live data into a a series of small 1 meter size samples.

In addition the independence assumption may be broken because the sampling is not truly random given the live data is likely going to be moving from area to area.  That is, at any given point there will be large areas of the domain that have never been sampled from until the end.

So the question becomes: **is there a way to use a continuous sample to perform a hypothesis test, and is there any way to account for the biases in the sampling process?**

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "live" here. Are you talking about testing data on-line as they come in? (Eg, you want to know when to stop collecting data b/c whether or not you have an effect is clear.) NB, if you have a number per unit (eg, 3 per mile), that is *not* a "proportion", but a **rate**. This should be distributed as a Poisson (likely w/ *overdispersion*), and you would need to include the unit as an *offset* if it varies over your data. Also, I suspect part of your issue is that you have *spacial autocorrelations* if these are counts in contiguous / adjacent locations.

Comment: Yes your example for live here is correct.  It will be online, and one item we want to calculate is when to we should stop collecting data or how much more we will need.  You are right this would be a poison, but it shouldn't vary.  The spacial auto-correlation is expected I am working on a way to account for it.

Comment: So it has become more obvious that phrasing this as a poisson means  assuming no bias I could simply use the chi square test to calcuate the confidence interval. I guess the issue as you state is how to handle the spacial autocorrelations.

Comment: I think the spacial autocorrelations will be a big deal. In addition, I suspect you will need to employ Bayesian methods to deal w/ the on-line stopping rules issue. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about either of those to advise you, but we'll see if we can get you more attention here on CV. There are people here who know these things well.

Comment: How many observations do you have, roughly?  I understand there is a stopping time involved, but are you expecting to see tens of observations, or thousands, or...?  (The motivation for asking is that some techniques work well with larger sample sizes but poorly with small sample sizes.)

Comment: This is a tricky question, given we like to assume we have sampled every point in the area searched for an occurrence.  So I would like to assume infinite.  So we could assume lots of samples if we just take this to mean very small increments. PS. Thank you all for your assistance.